# Where to add Rich snippet - Organization schema for a general page

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

Where do should be the Rich snippet - Organization schema for a school or group be placed?
Should this be placed on the Footer of every pages? Or in the header of every page? Or just in the homepage?

Just confused where this type of schema to put... I hope someone can clarify this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to put it on every page, but you should definitely insert it into pages such as the About page and Contact page, and you could also insert it into the homepage if there is an appropriate place for you to do so.  You will just want to be sure that the marked up content is also visible to your visitors.